# Multiple attempts to fix Error: linker command failed with exit code 1

Tags: objective-c, xcode, linker-errors

I've been working on this error for the last few days and am really stuck. I keep getting a linker command error and can't get past it. I've searched the web and tried all of the tips: Checked for duplicate files, reinstalled pods, set active architecture to NO, deleted derived data, cleaned lots of times.

Here's the output I'm given:

```
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_SessionPlayer._nextEvent in:
/Users/user1/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/***-APP-NAME-bahimtombyapwkcekphmmbaifpqx/Build/Intermediates/***-APP-NAME.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/***-APP-NAME.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/SessionPlayer.o
/Users/user1/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/***-APP-NAME-bahimtombyapwkcekphmmbaifpqx/Build/Intermediates/***-APP-NAME.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/***-APP-NAME.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/SessionPlayerViewController.o
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_SessionPlayer._visitors in:
/Users/user1/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/***-APP-NAME-bahimtombyapwkcekphmmbaifpqx/Build/Intermediates/***-APP-NAME.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/***-APP-NAME.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/SessionPlayer.o
/Users/user1/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/***-APP-NAME-bahimtombyapwkcekphmmbaifpqx/Build/Intermediates/***-APP-NAME.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/***-APP-NAME.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/SessionPlayerViewController.o
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_SessionPlayer._currentSessionTimeInMilliseconds in:
/Users/user1/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/***-APP-NAME-bahimtombyapwkcekphmmbaifpqx/Build/Intermediates/***-APP-NAME.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/***-APP-NAME.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/SessionPlayer.o
/Users/user1/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/***-APP-NAME-bahimtombyapwkcekphmmbaifpqx/Build/Intermediates/***-APP-NAME.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/***-APP-NAME.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/SessionPlayerViewController.o
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_SessionPlayer._systemTimeInMilliseconds in:
/Users/user1/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/***-APP-NAME-bahimtombyapwkcekphmmbaifpqx/Build/Intermediates/***-APP-NAME.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/***-APP-NAME.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/SessionPlayer.o
/Users/user1/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/***-APP-NAME-bahimtombyapwkcekphmmbaifpqx/Build/Intermediates/***-APP-NAME.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/***-APP-NAME.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/SessionPlayerViewController.o
duplicate symbol _OBJC_CLASS_$_SessionPlayer in:
/Users/user1/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/***-APP-NAME-bahimtombyapwkcekphmmbaifpqx/Build/Intermediates/***-APP-NAME.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/***-APP-NAME.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/SessionPlayer.o
/Users/user1/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/***-APP-NAME-bahimtombyapwkcekphmmbaifpqx/Build/Intermediates/***-APP-NAME.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/***-APP-NAME.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/SessionPlayerViewController.o
duplicate symbol _OBJC_METACLASS_$_SessionPlayer in:
/Users/user1/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/***-APP-NAME-bahimtombyapwkcekphmmbaifpqx/Build/Intermediates/***-APP-NAME.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/***-APP-NAME.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/SessionPlayer.o
/Users/user1/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/***-APP-NAME-bahimtombyapwkcekphmmbaifpqx/Build/Intermediates/***-APP-NAME.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/***-APP-NAME.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/SessionPlayerViewController.o
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_SessionPlayer._isPlaying in:
/Users/user1/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/***-APP-NAME-bahimtombyapwkcekphmmbaifpqx/Build/Intermediates/***-APP-NAME.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/***-APP-NAME.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/SessionPlayer.o
/Users/user1/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/***-APP-NAME-bahimtombyapwkcekphmmbaifpqx/Build/Intermediates/***-APP-NAME.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/***-APP-NAME.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/SessionPlayerViewController.o
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_SessionPlayer._useTiming in:
/Users/user1/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/***-APP-NAME-bahimtombyapwkcekphmmbaifpqx/Build/Intermediates/***-APP-NAME.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/***-APP-NAME.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/SessionPlayer.o
/Users/user1/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/***-APP-NAME-bahimtombyapwkcekphmmbaifpqx/Build/Intermediates/***-APP-NAME.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/***-APP-NAME.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/SessionPlayerViewController.o
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_SessionPlayer._delegate in:
/Users/user1/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/***-APP-NAME-bahimtombyapwkcekphmmbaifpqx/Build/Intermediates/***-APP-NAME.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/***-APP-NAME.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/SessionPlayer.o
/Users/user1/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/***-APP-NAME-bahimtombyapwkcekphmmbaifpqx/Build/Intermediates/***-APP-NAME.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/***-APP-NAME.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/SessionPlayerViewController.o
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_SessionPlayer._timeline in:
/Users/user1/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/***-APP-NAME-bahimtombyapwkcekphmmbaifpqx/Build/Intermediates/***-APP-NAME.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/***-APP-NAME.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/SessionPlayer.o
/Users/user1/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/***-APP-NAME-bahimtombyapwkcekphmmbaifpqx/Build/Intermediates/***-APP-NAME.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/***-APP-NAME.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/SessionPlayerViewController.o

ld: 10 duplicate symbols for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Really not sure what to do, it's very frustrating.

*EDIT:* Made the discovery that all of my files are being compiled twice, which may be where the problem lies.

Comment: Can you check if you've possibly `#import`ed `SessionPlayer.m` instead of `SessionPlayer.h` at the top of SessionPlayerViewController?

Comment: @BenZotto `SessionPlayerViewController.m` imports `SessionPlayer.h`

Comment: Hm. I believe that the error is telling you that several of the `SessionPlayer` instance variable symbols (`nextEvent`, `visitors`, `currentSessionTimeInMilliseconds`, etc) are appearing in *two* object files, which shouldn't happen. The object (.o) file is the build's intermediate output from compilation of each `.m` implementation. This can happen if you for some reason end up defining the same thing in two files (and the accidental import of a .m instead of a .h somewhere could do it, which I why I suggested that). Perhaps post the declaration of SessionPlayer?

Comment: @BenZotto I checked the compile log and noticed `sessionplayer.m `  is being compiled twice and that may be the source of the error. Not sure how to fix this

Comment: Actually all of the files are being compiled twice.

Comment: Are all of the files that are being compiled twice contained in pods, linked libraries, or the main project?  And, did you convert linked libraries over to pods at some point in your project's history?  If you don't remove all of the references to the linked library, you might get files to compile twice, once from a reference in the linked library and once from a reference in the pod.

Comment: @fullofsquirrels the files being compiled twice are in pods and the main project.

Comment: I suggest using Xcode's Product->Perform Action->Preprocess on the SessionPlayerViewController.m file.  Then search the output for references to `SessionPlayer` and see if something is pulling in its implementation.

Comment: @PhillipMills that just says "build failed" when I run it

Comment: Any better details if you look at the preprocess log in the Report Navigator?

Comment: @PhillipMills I see this: _No matching provisioning profile found: Your build settings specify a provisioning profile with the UUID “xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx”, however, no such provisioning profile was found._

Comment: @pico0102, any file that's in a pod doesn't need to be referenced separately in the main project as well.  You should just be able to remove all specific references to this (and other duplicate) file(s) from the main project.

Comment: @fullofsquirrels do you mean, any imports of a file that belongs to a pod is unnecessary and should be removed?

Comment: @pico0102, I'll post a more formal answer to help clarify what I mean.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you've included the source for `SessionPlayer.m` twice in your target's build.  Based on some comments, it's likely because you have references to the file *implicitly* through a pod (which is what you want), and *explicitly* via a direct reference/inclusion (which you *don't* want; that's what the pods are for).  Try doing the following (and I'll try to be as clear as I can in text, but if you have any questions I can include screenshots):

1. In the project navigator pane, select your project.
2. In the project editor window, select your app target (make sure it's not something like a UnitTest/LogicTest target).
3. Along the top of the project editor window, select "Build Phases"
4. In the main project editor window, there should now be a list of expandable sections, one of which is "Compile Source (xxx items)", where xxx is the number of source files used to build your target.  Expand that section.
5. In the search/filter text field (upper right hand corner of project editor, placeholder text says "Filter"), enter "SessionPlayer"
6. I suspect that you've included `SessionPlayer.m` explicitly here, so you should see at least one instance in the list.  Delete it by selecting the "-" button that appears at the bottom of the list.
7. Try rebuilding and see if at least the linker errors related to `SessionPlayer.m` disappear.  If so, repeat the previous steps for any other such files.

Hope this helps.

Comment: THIS WORKED!!!! It moved onto the test target with the same error. Did the same thing and now it built! You're amazing!

Comment: @pico0102 No, just experienced :)  I've been through the same pain, so glad I could help!